# Documentation example for datetime.fromisoformat raises invalid isoformat string error

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

In Python 3.10.8, if I write

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04T00:05:23Z'))
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04T00:05:23Z'))
ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2011-11-04T00:05:23Z'
```

This is surprising, since this example is taken directly out of the [`datetime` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
# ...
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04T00:05:23Z')
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Is this a bug or an error in the documentation?

Comment: No repro in 3.11

Comment: The documentation says too: "Changed in version 3.11: Previously, this method only supported formats that could be emitted by `date.isoformat()` or `datetime.isoformat()`.". Can those functions deliver a datestring with a trailing "Z" in Python 3.10.8?

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you, i'm sorry to have quick checked the docs.

Comment: see also [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49784038/10197418)

Answer (score 5):

Prior to Python 3.11, `fromisoformat` required the same format as `isoformat`.

Python `isoformat` did not support a trailing `Z` as an alias for +00:00, hence the error.

From the 3.10 docs:

> Caution - This does not support parsing arbitrary ISO 8601 strings - it is only intended as the inverse operation of datetime.isoformat()
> https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat

From the >=3.11 docs:

> Changed in version 3.11: Previously, this method only supported formats that could be emitted by date.isoformat() or datetime.isoformat(): https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat

Comment: _"Python isoformat does not contain Timezone information"_ seems misleading. Something like `datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04T00:05:23.234+04:00')` and `datetime(..., tzinfo=timezone.utc).isoformat()` were perfectly valid. It's just that using `Z` as an alias for `+00:00` wasn't supported.

Comment: Have clarified regarding the trailing Z.

Answer (score 0):

The example

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04T00:05:23Z')
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

in the `datetime` docs is only present in [Python 3.11+](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat). It's missing in [Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat).

The ability for `datetime.isoformat` to parse a trailing `Z` suffix as an alias for `+00:00` was introduced in [BPO 35829](https://bugs.python.org/issue35829)  / [BPO 46614](https://bugs.python.org/issue46614) for Python 3.11.